# How to get the socket used by HttpURLConnection in java

Tags: java, sockets, httpconnection

There is a socket which HttpURLConnection use internally to send data. 
I know it is now visible from outside, but I am wondering if there's any workaround so that I could get access to this socket (without changing the implementation of HttpURLConnection)?
I need this hack to do some instrumentation.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What are you really trying to do?  That is, if you actually could get the socket, what "hack to do some instrumentation" would you attempt. I have some ideas, but I need to know more before I reply back.

Comment: @selbie I need to call setsockopt or ioctl to set some custom flag on that socket (tos field, among others). Ultimately I will need to identify the packets sent through this socket later in a switch. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sockets are created by [Socket Factories](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/net/SocketFactory.html). You can write your own SocketFactory, delegating to the original socket factory. In your Socket Factory, you can manipulate the socket. That's one way I can think of for you to get access to the socket, but I'm going to warn you in advance - it's not going to be pretty.

Comment: If I write my own socket factory, will that be factory be used by all my application's network related activity, or can I specify just one (or two) connections to use that factory?

Comment: Also, if would be best if I could change the flags of the socket at run-time -- not just when they are created. Is that possible?

Comment: A socket factory is JVM-wide (well, more precisely, classloader-wide). All socket requests will go through your Socket Factory. But if you design your socket factory as a wrapper, you can delegate all "non-interesting" socket creations to the *default* socket factory, and only handle the ones you really are interested in.

Comment: how does he register his implementation of SocketFactory? Such that subsequent socket usage goes through his factory?

Comment: I will try use reflection to get the runtime class instance of httpconnection, and then use jni to access its protected/private fields. I will let you guys know the results.

Comment: @yangsuli Excuse me. Would you mind to share which  protected/private fields to be reflected?